# Selecting the same values in the same column

Tags: mysql

Okay I have this problem I want to show which articles have the same price

I have a table like this:

[image]

So I want to show computer and tv because they have the same price, I have looked everywhere and I haven't found anything close to what I want. I have seen the count but I don't want that

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: @danny , please provide desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Group_concat(`article`) AS `article`
FROM   `table`
GROUP  BY `price`
```

Or only the specific records with same price:

```
SELECT Group_concat(`article`) AS `article`,
       Count(*)                AS total
FROM   `table`
GROUP  BY `price`
HAVING total > 1
```